# How to select columns if column names contain digits?

Tags: r, dplyr

With `str_detect` I am able to find out if column names contain digits, but it returns logical TRUE or FALSE. How do I use it to select columns instead?

**Code**

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)


data <- tribble(
  ~a1, ~b, ~c91, ~d,
  1, 2, 3, 4
)


data %>% 
  select(str_detect("[[:digit:]]", names(.)))
```

The code returns this error

```
Error: Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
x Subscript has the wrong type `logical`.
i It must be numeric or character.
```

Comment: R has logical indexing. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+select+columns+pattern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dplyr` comes with a set of helper functions to match column names in select.

You want:

```
data %>% 
  select(matches("[[:digit:]]"))
```

The issue here is that `str_detect()` returns a vector of booleans but `select()` expects column names.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base R alternative -

```
data[grepl('[[:digit:]]', names(data))]

#     a1   c91
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     3
```

Comment: I can understand why it’s easier to put in an answer but for a question that is clearly a many times over a duplicate?